# HP Laptop (HP pavilion 15 ck018nl) and NVME specs

Tags: laptop, ssd, hp-pavilion, nvme, m2-connector

I have this laptop and I'd like to replace it's 120GiB M2 SATA with an NVMe one but I can't find the specs of the slot, could please someone help me, the motherboard is the HP841C (yes, it has the same name as a printr from the early '00).
For what I know it supports the NVMe M2 and also the SATA over M2 but It's not clear what version of NVMe. Could someone help me telling how to figure it out?

Thanks

EDIT:
My issue is: should I get pcie gen4, pcie gen3 or pcie gen2, is the slot on the board type B or type M (I've not yet opened the machine), are the slot x2 or x4?

Comment: Get whatever you can justify. Gen4 might well be faster, but chances are you'll never notice or appreciate the speed unless you have a top-end graphics card. Same goes for x2 and x4. Nothing about a laptop screams "You must get Gen4 x4!" so aim for what you can justify in terms of cost and additional storage, and *then* look at which one is faster.

Comment: It does not matter what version of NVMe (PCIe 4.0) your device supports since the standard is backwards compatible.  However, NVMe (PCIe 4.0) drives just came out in the last 2 years.  AMD and Intel didn't even offer motherboard chipsets that supported it until then.  There are no PCIe 2.0 NVMe drives on the market.  We can't tell you what type of slot your device supports.  You need to look at the device yourself to determine that, simplest method, look up your current storage device.

Comment: (AT)Ramhound Current storage is SATA over M2 but it supports also NVMe over M2 but I'd like to have some performace improvement alongside with increased space. (AT)Mokubai What I need is actually just more space but, the current speed is enough (for now), but a little premium for increased speed is acceptable. The devices I'm looking at are Samsung 970 evo plus and 980 Pro (200€), the 980 (140€). and the 970 evo plus (150€)

Answer (score 1):

Your model supports these Solid State Drives drives

[image]

[Your support page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-pavilion-15-ck000-laptop-pc/17296798/model/20017746/manuals)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I edited the question to add further details (I already found that document)