# Samsung 970 EVO Plus running half speed

Tags: ssd, nvme, samsung-ssd

My SSD (Samsung 870 Evo Plus) reaches maximum speeds of 1700 MB/s instead of the 3200 advertised.
I checked with hwinfo and it says PCI-E 3.0, max Width 4x current link w. 4x, max speed 8GT/s

So my drive is running at 4x, also I tried to reposition it physically.

What else could it be (My pc is an HP 15ck018nl)?

[image]

NOTE: SSD-SMART temperature is reported to be 42 °C

EDIT: Can't open it (again) but [this is HP's service manual](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s5qoabrqcpn15lt/manuale%20smontaggio%20pc%20ufficio%20c05709135.pdf?dl=0) (dropbox link because I'm not able to find the site again)

EDIT2:
According to the label the PC is:
RMN: TPN-Q201
Laptop model: 15-ck018nl
Product Id: 3DK73EA#ABZ

Motherboard ID: 841C 64.14 (from HP assistant)

Comment: What is your motherboard and what have you connected to it and in which slots?

Comment: @harrymc I think the motherboard is HP841C which is also the name of a printer. https://superuser.com/questions/1667269/hp-laptop-hp-pavilion-15-ck018nl-and-nvme-specs

Comment: Curious... NVMEs tend to plug into a connector that's soldered on the board and be screwed on from tail end to boot, so how does one go about physically repositioning one? If I'm not badly mistaken, PCI-e 3 4x max 8GT/s translates to bus speed 4GB/s, unidirectional (wiser persons will correct me). Can't find a diagram, maybe that SATA drive sits in the same PCI-e bus. How exactly are you measuring the transfer rate?

Comment: As far as I can see there is no such motherboard. If you can, open the computer and take a good photo, and tell us what the label says.

Comment: @harrymc it is a laptop. Taking a good photo of a laptop motherboard is gonna be rather difficult.

Comment: @harrymc  I have no photos but I added the service manual for the model

Comment: You can get more precise info in [How Do I Find My Product Name or Number?](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00033108)

Comment: @harrymc Trust me the motherboard is called HP 841C. Or "Steve".

Comment: https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-pavilion-15-ck000-laptop-pc/17296798/model/20017746/product-info

Comment: There are many variants, the exact model could help.

Comment: The exact model, as added to the question, is 3DK73EA#ABZ google got me to the exact datasheet: https://media.flixcar.com/f360cdn/HP-2751851727-c05846328.pdf

Comment: Have you updated UEFI to latest version? That often fixes many issues.

Comment: Yes, I updated it.